# QGIS Invalid object name 'geometry_columns' QODBC3:Unable to execute statement

Tags: qgis

I was using Lisboa 1.8 with SQL Express and tables with geometry. Connections were working with 1.8 and are working with ArcGIS, so I know my tables and geometry are fine. I installed 2.4 Chugiak, mapped my SQL Server, test connection works fine, but now I get:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] 
Invalid object name 'geometry_columns'. 
QODBC3:Unable to execute statement.
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong all of a sudden? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just overlooked the "Only look in the geometry_columns metadata table" checkbox when you created new MSSQL connection. It is checked by default, so if geometry_columns table does not exist, you get that error message.

Comment: I have fixed this bug in 2.10 and 2.8.3 (unreleased).  It will now tell you about the issue and let you do a full database scan.